# Altium: Two adjacent Prepreg layers in stack manager

Tags: altium, pcb-layers

Is there a way to add two adjacent prepreg layers in the Altium Layer Stack Manager? When you add a layer it adds copper as well, and when you remove the copper it removes the dielectric. I am attempting to mimic a suggested layer stack from Advanced Circuits, which requires two prepreg layers immediately adjacent to one another. Here is the [document](http://www.4pcb.com/media/prepreg-thickness-chart.pdf) that calls out that requirement.

I currently have a single prepreg layer in my stackup that has a thickness of the two sheets together (i.e. one sheet is 4.7 mil and one is 3.5 mil, so Altium has a prepreg layer that is 8.2 mil thick). I would like to be able to show both layers individually in the live Layer Stack Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too sought such feature. There's a menu on top right corner of the Layer Stack Manager window, which is set to "Layer Pairs" by default. If you change it to "Custom," you'll be able to add various kinds of layers in arbitrary order.

Comment: Right on, this is the way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

In ALtium just add a single copper layer. Give Altium the overall dielectric thickness for that layer (~10 mil in this case).

In the layer stack manager call out the material as "2 sheets 2116" or whatever you want. Then when you generate a stackup drawing or layer stack table on your fab drawing layer, this information will be included.

Comment: Ok, that's not too much different from what I have now, I would just need to change the material comment. I was hoping there was a way to show the independent layers though so that I could call out individual thicknesses, but as far as I can tell there's not a way to do that.

Comment: I'm intensely curious what the heck you're doing that needs to be specified to that level. I've never had an FR4 design where I needed to specify the weave, much less the exact order of layers of prepregs.

Comment: Also, it's a kludge but you could place the stackup detail in your drawing, then manually edit to specify additional detail that Altium doesn't understand how to represent.

Comment: My apologies, I never saw these comments. These designs required controlled dielectric/impedance with high precision, and that involved calling out prepreg that would settle after baking to a known thickness. That was standard at my old job, I would do this for every board I designed. Ultimately I began generating the layer stackup graphically in Excel and supplying that to the manufacturer. The stackup spreadsheet was called out in the fabrication drawings.

Comment: Another option: Draw the stackup detail in something (Autocad, Inkscape, ...) that can output DXF, and import it into the drawing layer in Altium.

Comment: I can draw the stackup on mechanical layers in Altium, so that would also be possible. I find it much more reliable, however, to have a separate stackup file that can be sent to the manufacturer. A lot of manufacturers don't even look at some of the mechanical layers.

Comment: I usually use the Drill Drawing layer as a fab drawing, and use two mechanical layers as top and bottom assembly drawings. Then I make PDFs from those layers and send them with the data rather than crossing my fingers that the shop will find the drawings in the gerber data.

Comment: I generally create mechanical drawings in SolidWorks for fab and assembly. It's a very neat, 3D method of showing how things are supposed to be put together.

Comment: For me an assembly drawing shows the locations of all the parts by designator. Keeping that coordinated between Altium and another tool seems a bit fussy? If you mean assembly to show how the PCB is fit into an enclosure, then yes, I've used SW that way too.

Comment: Ah, we have a different definition of "Assembly drawing". My fab drawing has all of the part designators and locations. My assembly drawing shows the manufacturer how it is to be assembled, as well as any restrictions or instructions (type of solder, IPC standards, cleaning, mounting requirements, alignment/GD&T dimensioning, etc). If I have an alignment pin, for example, I would display it in the assembly drawing with a note and GD&T showing perpendicularity, position, height, and other requirements associated with that part.